# How to route all undefined actions to root_url in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have 6 controllers currently, and not everyone has defined all 6 actions. I'm hoping to route all undefined actions to root_url so we don't have that ugly error message but can't figure out a way to do that. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Letting your users know that a page does not exist is important. You shouldn't just redirect them to the route. `404` pages aren't all that bad. You can pretty it up and give the user some options, even redirect them automatically after showing the message.

Comment: The problem is, if you specify an action in the address bar, which is not defined in the controller, it does not even show 404, but just display a white page saying the action is not defined.

Comment: Yes, this is because you're on a development environment. As a developer, you need to know if you have or have not defined your routes correctly; you can easily forget, some times and Rails makes you aware of this. In a production environment, however, this does not happen. You see a 404 error, not the same message you're seeing now.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out in the comments, you probably do not actually want to do what you are asking, however, since you asked it, the solution you are looking for is a few lines added to your `ApplicationController`.

```
unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local
  rescue_from AbstractController::ActionNotFound, with: :handle_error
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :handle_error
  rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, with: :handle_error
  rescue_from ActionController::UnknownController, with: :handle_error
  rescue_from ActionController::UnknownAction, with: :handle_error
end

protected
def handle_error
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

This will basically catch all errors around missing routes, controllers, and actions and redirect to the root_url. Since it is in your ApplicationController, which all your other controllers derive from, it works for all of your missing things.

Please note that because I wrapped those rescues in that unless, you will still see the errors in your local dev which you want so that you can deal with any real problems.

Again, you are probably better off putting some custom pages around the different error types like 404, 500, etc and then either redirecting the user or letting them navigate themselves.

As of rails 3.2 you can even direct these errors to a specific rack end point (including the app itself) and deal with them however you want. This is much nicer than the solution above, but only works on rails 3.2 or later. For older versions the above solution will work.

To do this you would add this line to your application.rb

```
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

Then, in your routes file you can do things like this:

```
match '/404', to: "error_pages#handle_404"
```

That expects you to have an ErrorPages controller with a handle_404 action but you can also just route it to where ever, including your root_url, whatever that is. You can do this for all of the error codes.

Answer (score 0):

In the undefined actions of each controller, just write:

```
redirect_to root_url
```

Comment: Is there any way to simply redirect ALL undefined actions? It seems tedious to finish all other actions with the same content.

Comment: @OneZero What you want to do does not make sense. What's your issue with undefined actions? Very few people will write a url that does not exist in the address bar, and if they do, too bad, it's their fault.

Comment: It doesn't seem that tedious to me. It just one line of code really. And what dee said is also true; what are the chances a user will reach one of those undefined actions?